# Tap + Hold + Drag to select option

Tags: jquery, mobile, gesture

Folks,

I've been trying to find this functionality, but since I cannot find the correct term to which to refer to it, I have not yet found. It is the combo of tap and hold and then once you hold for a certain time, several icons appear in the area and you drag your finger to one such option to accept it.

What is the correct term for this gesture and is there a jQuery plugin for it?

Comment: Pretty sure it's called `long press`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using some kind of gesture event library like [Hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) and then the `hold` event.